# Create a Microsoft Account (developer's license) without a phone number

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I am trying to create a Windows store app, and have installed Visual Studio 2012 Express, but I have been confronted with a request for a developer's license. When I try to create one, they expect me to give them my phone number and name. How can I create a Microsoft Account, or developer's license without giving my personal details?

Comment: (1) [Microsoft account security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account#microsoft-account-security) has this sentence: "You must have at least two email addresses or phone numbers on your Microsoft account". Try maybe to add more email addresses. (2) A developer license is not required in Windows 10 to develop and test. It is enabled in *Settings > Update & security > For developers* and click on Developer mode and Yes. Finally close Settings and reboot.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser: Does the above comment help?

Answer (score 6):

You can't. That's the point of windows store.

Comment: Some folks don't have a phone. We are part of a non-trivial portion of the US population (according to latest CDC statistics). I refused to pay over $100/month to have spammers and telemarketers call me. I cut service about 4 years ago. My life is peaceful now, and I don't suffer the constant interruptions. Microsoft policy meant I stopped supporting Windows Store apps about 4 years ago. The same applies to Apple.

Comment: You can't even create a Twitter account without a phone. It gets immediately flagged as spam. That's 2019.

Answer (score 3):

The number is wanted as a security check.
Try using a fake SMS text receiver - (this has worked before)
It is not 100% reliable as it may not be accepted as a real number.

Answer (score 0):

I think providing no email address is impossible. But you can try the method below so that you don't need any phone number, since that's what your are asking for. You still need a device with internet (can be any device, as long as it support the Microsoft Authenticator functionality, even the Windows Store provide apps that supports those features but I didn't try those in combination with the setup below).

The method below is still a preview feature of Azure AD, but functional and I use it in many scenario's already.

In your Azure tenant (if you don't have one, you can create it with a free trial for example), go to Azure AD > User settings > User feature previews > Manage user feature preview settings.
[image]

Enable: Users can use preview features for registering and managing security info – enhanced

After that, go to https://aka.ms/setupsecurityinfo (you can also create a clean user and use that user for the visual studio subscription).
On that page, you can assign a second factor with the Microsoft Authenticator app, without providing your phone number. Last but not least, add the Visual Studio subscription to this user.

Give it a try.